# Its possible insert row with embedded ID on table with HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql, bulkinsert

I'm able to insert any row with HQL.

Example:

```
insert into MyMappedTable(field,field,field) select c.x, c.y, c.z from Object c where ....
```

But, my requirement is insert with embedded Id

```
@JoinColumn(insertable = false, name = "CATEGORYID", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
private Category category;

@EmbeddedId
protected CategoryProductPK categoryProductPK;

@Basic(optional = true)
@Column(name = "POSITION")
private Integer position;

@JoinColumn(insertable = false, name = "PRODUCTID", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
private Product product;
```

Is possible with HQL?

Comment: I have never used HQL for inserts. It is an odd thing to do. Just save the entity a normal way.

Comment: Yes, I would do in normal situations, but this is not. Im able only do HQL queries. So, with HQL plain is not possible?