# INSERT SELECT with an entity that has its key defined as EmbeddableId

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpql

I have the following entity which has its primary key defined as `@EmbeddableId`.

```
@Entity
public class TeamResult implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TeamMatchdayKey primaryKey;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long matchdayResult;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long afterMatchdayResult;

    // ...
}
```

The `Embeddable` class `TeamMatchdayKey` looks as follows.

```
@Embeddable
public class TeamMatchdayKey implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Team team;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Matchday matchday;

    //...
}
```

The relevant parts of the `Team` entity used in the HQL query that follows look like that

```
@Entity
public final class Team implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(length = 40)
    private String name = "";

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="primaryKey.team", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @MapKey(name = "primaryKey.matchday")
    @OrderBy("primaryKey.matchday")
    private SortedMap<Matchday, TeamResult> teamResults = new TreeMap<>();

    // ...
}
```

Now I want to write the following `INSERT ... SELECT ...` query in JPQL...

```
INSERT INTO TeamResult (primaryKey.team, primaryKey.matchday, matchdayResult, afterMatchdayResult)
  SELECT t.team, (SELECT MAX(m) from Matchday m), 0, COALESCE(tr.afterMatchdayResult, 0)
  FROM Team t JOIN t.teamResults tr
  WHERE tr IS EMPTY OR KEY(tr).matchdayNumber = (SELECT MAX(matchdaynumber) - 1 FROM Matchday) ORDER BY tr.afterMatchdayResult DESC, t
```

...however it does seem to be incorrect as its compilation upon starting the web app gives me the following exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:  of: com.example.entities.stats.TeamResult
```

As you can see there is no property name in the error message, so I tried with the following...

```
INSERT INTO TeamResult (team, matchday, matchdayResult, afterMatchdayResult)
  SELECT t.team, (SELECT MAX(m) from Matchday m), 0, COALESCE(tr.afterMatchdayResult, 0)
  FROM Team t JOIN t.teamResults tr
  WHERE tr IS EMPTY OR KEY(tr).matchdayNumber = (SELECT MAX(matchdaynumber) - 1 FROM Matchday) ORDER BY tr.afterMatchdayResult DESC, t
```

... this however gives me the following message

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: team of: com.example.entities.stats.TeamResult
```

This message is understandable for me, as I know there is no `team` property but it is rather hidden in my embeddable.

Is there any way to define `INSERT ... SELECT` query in HQL/JPQL for an entity that has its primary key defined as `@EmbeddableId`?

Comment: You need to refer to these attributes following the OOP way like this `primaryKey.team`.

Comment: @chsdk But this is what I do in the first place. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Can you please post the whole query with the `SELECT`part?!*

Comment: @chsdk: Here you are but I do not think the problem is there, as it is clearly about the first attribute after `INSERT TeamResult(`.

Comment: can you post the relevant part of team entity too?

Comment: @Zeromus Here you are. The relevant parts of `Team` entity are now there.

Comment: There is a similar unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193573/its-possible-insert-row-with-embedded-id-on-table-with-hql) asked over 5 years ago. It looks like it is not possible at all.